# onReceive doesn't perform when I switched view on TabView in swiftUI

Tags: swift, timer, swiftui, tabview

When I first launched the app, the app shows current time well, but if I tab second and got back to the first tab, the app no more updates current time. 
Like a video below

[image]
    struct ContentView: View {
        @State private var selection = 0

```
    @State var currentDate = Date()
    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()

    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selection){

            VStack{
                Text("\(currentDate)")
                .onReceive(timer) { input in
                    self.currentDate = input
                }
            }
                .tabItem {
                    VStack {
                        Image("first")
                        Text("First")
                    }
                }
                .tag(0)


            Text("Second View")
                .font(.title)
                .tabItem {
                    VStack {
                        Image("second")
                        Text("Second")
                    }
                }
                .tag(1)
        }
    }
}
```